# Background attribute doesn't show up in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, internet-explorer-7

I have a div with height and width, and it has a background image assigned to it in the stylesheet. It works fine in Firefox/Chrome, but in IE8 and below the image just doesn't show up. In the developer the background attribute doesn't even show up as one of the styles. I can add background color and that does work. Does anyone know why this might be?

For reference the attribute looks something like this:

```
 background: url("imgpath.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 position:relative
```

Edit: the HTML is just a div within a larger wrapper. Other images in the wrapper that are defined in the same way work.

Comment: Can you please show us the `HTML` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think I know what it might be. Try to put the whole image path there including the protocol and domain, just like that: `background: url("http://example.com/imgpath/image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;`

And tell me if it works or not.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Do you know why IE wouldn't accept it otherwise? I have other others defined using local path that load fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea why, but I've frequently used this method when adding fixes for IE conditional specific stylesheets. I found this way accidentally.
By the way, thanks for selecting my answer. I'm happy my very first post here was useful for someone. =)

Answer (score 3):

I will blatantly assume that `imgpath.png` is CMYK. IE8 only supports RGB images.

Try converting it from CMYK to RGB using this [CMYK Converter](http://www.cmykconverter.com/).

Comment: +1 and support for your agrument : http://www.plaveb.com/blog/cmyk-images-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer